# "singleton" pattern method best way in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Can someone help me to find a better way to create a single instance in Kotlin?

```
class Bar(private val blub) {

   private lateinit var foo: FooService
   private lateinit var doo: DooService

   override fun getFooService(): FooService {
       if (!::foo.isInitialized) {
           foo = FooService(blub)
       }
       return foo
   }

    override fun getDooService(): DooService {
       if (!::doo.isInitialized) {
           doo = DooService(blub)
       }
       return doo
   }
}
```

**Edit:**
I don't want to init every object at beginning - should be only done when needed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if all you want is to lazily initialize your `FooService` use [`by lazy`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html#lazy) - if you want a singleton with parameter on the other hand, have a look at https://medium.com/@BladeCoder/kotlin-singletons-with-argument-194ef06edd9e which is basically nothing more than double checked locking singleton pattern with a volatile field. Your code is not threadsafe.

Comment: Thanks zapl. I'm searching a kotlin way to solve this with less code as possible. :) Anyway thanks for helping!

Answer (score 2):

If your `FooService` doesn't take any parameters via the getter for its initialization, you can use an [`object`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-declarations) for this:

```
object FooHolder {
    val foo: FooService = FooService(...)
}
```

Otherwise, your pattern seems just fine, the alternative would be to use a nullable variable instead of `lateinit`, but they're essentially the same:

```
private var foo: FooService? = null

override fun getService(): FooService {
    if (foo == null) {
        foo = FooService(...)
    }
    return foo!!
}
```

Comment: Thanks for hint with object. Unfortunately this would not help for me as you already mention in you answer :( .... Anyway thanks for helping!

Comment: In that case, what you're doing is the way to go, whether with the null check or the `lateinit` solution.

Answer (score 2):

Your class is not looking as singleton. Maybe you want something like this

```
class Bar(private val blub) {

    var foo by lazy{ FooService(blub) }
}
```

OR you can put it in companion object to have the same instance between all objects

Comment: As you already said lazy would not provide an instance between all objects. Do you know how I can forward params from constructor (like in example: blub) to companion object?. Thanks for helping! :)